# Inject a distinctive class variable into a metaprogrammed class

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, metaprogramming

I'm trying to metaprogram some tests that run tests on files.
I want to create a test class for every file.
Every class should have the filename as class variable or equivalent so that it executes the tests on the correct file. However, I cannot find a way to define these variables distinctively for each class. All will have the same class variable in my current code.
How can I achieve this?

```
module SomeFileTest
  # create a test class for every profile
  Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/*.json') do |file|
    # test class
    test_class = Class.new(MiniTest::Unit::TestCase) do
       # this var should be the #{file} var for each iteration
      @@filename = file
      @json

      def setup
        begin
          @json = JSON.parse(File.read(@@filename))
        rescue JSON::ParserError
          assert(@json != nil, "JSON structure is not wellformed")
        end
      end

      # test some things in te file
      define_method("test_duplicates") do
        # ...
      end

    end

    # self-descriptive classname
    filename = File.basename(file, ".json")
    classname = "Test#{filename.capitalize}"
    self.const_set(classname, test_class)

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `@@filename` is a class variable. Class variables behave a bit counter intuitively in ruby when it comes to inheritance, which is why I usually avoid them. Try this instead:

```
module SomeFileTest
  # create a test class for every profile
  Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/*.json') do |file|
    # test class
    test_class = Class.new(MiniTest::Unit::TestCase) do
       # this var should be the #{file} var for each iteration
      @filename = file
      def self.filename
        @filename
      end
      @json

      def setup
        begin
          @json = JSON.parse(File.read(self.class.filename))
        rescue JSON::ParserError
          assert(@json != nil, "JSON structure is not wellformed")
        end
      end

      # test some things in te file
      define_method("test_duplicates") do
        # ...
      end

    end

    # self-descriptive classname
    filename = File.basename(file, ".json")
    classname = "Test#{filename.capitalize}"
    self.const_set(classname, test_class)

  end
end
```